# PostgreSQL - pgAdmin error creating a server

Tags: postgresql, linux, pgadmin, setup

I have the latest versions of PostgreSQL and its GUI-frontend, pgAdmin, installed.
When I try to register a new server a fatal error appears when pgAdmin tries to connect to the newly created server - **password authentication failed for user "postgres"**. 
I'm using a non-default port which was properly updated in the postgresql.conf file so I don't believe that is causing problems (restarted postgres too, as it so politely asks you to).
postgres processes are running properly:
[image: picture_1]

Here you can examine the configuration settings I am using to register the server:
[image: picture_2]

I've tried a few passwords, including my root password but none of them appear to be working. Maybe the user has to be created separately?

This is the first time I'm encountering anything besides SQL Server or Access so please bear with me if the question and its possible solution seem far too trivial.
I'm running Linux Mint 15, 32-bit.
I will provided additional information, if needed of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enter the password of the *database* user, not the OS user. The "root password" is not applicable. Do you know the password of the database user `postgres`?

Most systems are set up allowing [peer authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) for *local* connections, meaning a system user can log into the database with a database user of the same name without password. `localhost` is *not* a local connection. Its privileges are determined by `host` entries in your [`pg_hba.conf` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Since you seem to be running Postgres and pgAdmin on the same server, I suggest you try a *local* connection *without password*. [Quoting the pgAdmin manual:](http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/connect.html)

> On Unix based systems, the address field may be **left blank to use the
>   default PostgreSQL Unix Domain Socket on the local machine**, or be set
>   to an alternate path containing a PostgreSQL socket.

Bold emphasis mine.
Of course, you have to run pgAdmin as the system user `postgres` for this to work.

[This related answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100) has a lot more details and links.

Comment: If I try it when leaving the password field blank it also causes an error - "Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied". I've also tried disabling the "Store password" option but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the address field blank as instructed? It is labeled "Host".

Comment: Tried it now, I receive this error - Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres". This is getting ridiculous.

Comment: System user and database user names have to match, of course. Try running pgAdmin as system user `postgres`. Other than that, study the manual and set up `pg_hba.conf` properly.

Comment: I'll try that after a good nights sleep, thank you for your advice. I'll post an update if I manage to make it work.

Comment: I've managed to get it fully working, apparently by fiddling around with the pg_hba.conf file. I've used the "trust" identification method for user "postgres". Also, I've had to install the contrib package but that isn't connected to this particular problem. Thank you for your good advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this type of error is faced by most user who are new to pgadmin.I have found below solution and it worked for me hope this will work for you as well.

I used below commands on my `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` recently.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

This will ask for your system password and then you will get the PostgreSQL prompt.

and then in psql type below command to change the password.

```
\password
```

Now enter the new password and re-enter it. That's ok! then you can sign in. In this matter there is no need to change the configuration of `pg_hba.conf file`.
After following these steps you can make new server connection registration and then make new database to continue working.